# Ocaml error Printf.printf

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
let main() = 
let base = read_int () in
let num = read_int () in
if num = reverse num && (is_base base num) = true then Printf.printf "YES"
else if is_base base num = false then Printf.printf "ERROR" 
else Printf.printf"NO"
```

This expression has type

```
     ('a -> 'b -> 'c, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, 'a -> 'b -> 'c)
     CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
   but an expression was expected of type
     ('a -> 'b -> 'c, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
     CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
   Type 'a -> 'b -> 'c is not compatible with type unit
```

I've read the documentation, but it's still not clear how printf works in Ocaml.
It works in toplevel. Maybe some library missing?

Comment: Printf.printf is used in classical sense : Printf.printf "format string" arg1 arg2... . No library missing. I dare to think that there is some missing parenthesis in your code. Just try it with fewer statements.

Comment: Quick note: `is_base base num = true` is redundant, you can write just `is_base base num`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a high probability the next line of your code is

```
main ()
```

or a similar toplevel expression, and this is the true source of your error. Toplevel expression needs to be introduced by `;;`:

```
;; main ()
```

Another idiom is to rather write

```
let () = main ()
```

to avoid introducing toplevel expressions at all

Now, why did you get such a complicated type error? The answer is quite interestings and stems from the left-to-right bias of the typechecker and the flexibility of `printf`. Everything starts when we write:

```
 Printf.printf "ERROR" main ()
```

Here, the type of Printf.printf is `('a, out_channel, unit) format -> 'a` which means:

- `'a`: printf takes a format string plus as many argument as required by the format
- `out_channel`: it writes on a `out_channel`
- `unit` : ultimately, it returns unit.

But then, when typing the function application,
`Printf.printf "Error" main ()`, the typechecker sees that `Printf.printf` is applied to three argument, it thus deduces that the type `'a` can be expanded to `'b -> 'c -> 'd`. But then, the typechecker looks at the type of the format argument `"ERROR": ('e, 'f, 'e) format`, it infers thus that the return type of the format should be `'b -> 'c -> 'd`. But this is a contradiction with the fact that `Printf.printf` required unit as a return type, leading to your type error (after a  bit of simplification):

```
 ('a -> 'b -> 'c, out_channel,'a -> 'b -> 'c) format
 but an expression was expected of type
 ('a -> 'b -> 'c, out_channel, unit) format
 Type 'a -> 'b -> 'c is not compatible with type unit
```